# Use css calc() in jquery

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, css-calc

How can I do this?

```
$('#element').animate({ "width": "calc(100% - 278px)" }, 800);
$('#element').animate({ "width": "calc(100% - 78px)" }, 800);
```

I can do it if it's only `%` or only `px`, but not `calc()`, can I use some other option of jQuery? or some other trick of JavaScript?

It's a change that have to be done when the user clicks some element, so:

```
$("#otherElement").on("click", FunctionToToggle);
```

when the user clicks the `$("#otherElement")` the toggle effect has to occur.

Comment: You can create a CSS rule with the calc rule in it, add a class to the object that causes the CSS rule to go into effect and use CSS3 transitions for the animation.

Comment: Great answer, but I have another problem if I do this, and it's that I have some other animations with jquery.animate, and they have to match the speed, and with transition, it's not looking the same. Great answer anyway.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

maybe this helps:

```
$('#element').animate({ "width": "-=278px" }, 800);
```

every time this script will remove 278px from the element

edit:
Try this it will recalculate when the window is resized. If i understand you correctly that should help.

```
$(window).on("resize",function(){
   $('#element').css("width",$('#element').width()-275+"px");
});
```

**CSS3 option**

Since CSS3 has an animateion function you could also use this:

```
#element{
   -webkit-transition:all 500ms ease-out 0.5s;
   -moz-transition:all 500ms ease-out 0.5s;
   -o-transition:all 500ms ease-out 0.5s;
   transition:all 500ms ease-out 0.5s;
}
```

If you want to animate the element.
And you could do this:

```
 $('#element').css("width","calc(100% - 100px)");
```

In this case the CSS will do the animation.

*Please notice that this will not work for older browsers*

Comment: Yes that will do the trick, but then, when i change the size of my window, dosen't have the behaviour of % so, it's like giving the element a fixed amount of widht with px, instead of doing the clac(), sorry for my bad explanation.

Comment: So if i understand you correctly you want to have a element that is 100% of they page minus some pixels that resize with the page?

Comment: If @Rickdep is correct then I imagine there is a simpler CSS solution to your problem. Can you post some sample code for us to look at?

Comment: For those who got here looking for a way to add dynamic size to `calc()`, this seems to work:  `$my_element.css("height","calc(100vh - " + offset_top + "px)");`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure using `calc` is going to work out. My answer checks the parent's width, then performs an operation on it, and then animates the element.

```
elWidth = $('#element').parent().width(); // Get the parent size instead of using 100%
elWidth -= 20; // Perform any modifications you need here
$('#element').animate({width: elWidth}, 500); //Animate the element
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yKVz2/2/

Comment: Yes that will do the trick, but then, when i change the size of my window, dosen't have the behaviour of % so, it's like giving the element a fixed amount of widht with px, instead of doing the clac(), sorry for my bad explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I have found another form of doing it with the help of the coment of @jfriend00.

First I create the rule of CSS but without transition.

And in the funcion of the toggle:

```
$('#element').animate({ width: "-=200px" }, 800, function () { $('#element').addClass('acoreonOpened');$('#element').removeAttr("style") });
```

.acoreonOpened is where I have the CSS rule with calc (100% - 278px).

So, first i make the animation with jquery, and when it ends, i remove the style that jquery uses (if not, the css will not work), and after i put the class, so it behaves like a width with %.