# Using CSS calc() with .animate()

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, css-calc

I'm trying to make a little animation but I'm failing to make it responsive, because "calc()" seems to not work with .animate.
Is there another solution to this here?

```
if (time == 1) {
  $("#message").animate({ marginTop: "calc(-15px + .8vw)" });
} else {
  $("#message").animate({ marginTop: "calc(0px + .8vw)" });
}
```

With great and best regards,
BERNARDO

EDIT: I'm trying to animate a message that appears on my website onchange() of a dropdown menu.
It should be responsive so that's why I'm using calc().

```
<a>Time: </a><select id="time" onchange="setTime()" name="time" required>
                    <option value="1" selected>-</option>
                    <option value="3">-</option>
              </select></br>
```

So is there like an alternative to make it responsive on another way without calc()?

Comment: jQuery doesn't understand `calc()`, it only understands numbers

Comment: No, `calc()` doesn't work with `animate()`, however I'm sure there's an alternative method for whatever it is you're trying to do. Could you please update the question to give details of what effect you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Setting calc() like you want won't work. The easiest way to do it is to "calculate" it's value into a variable.

Comment: You can use CSS variables and jq-cssvar and CSS transition (instead of animation via JQuery)

Comment: can't you just toggle classes and do animation in css?

Comment: Oh right, @VilleKoo that could be a very good solution, I'll  try that! Regards to everybody and thanks to for your time.

Comment: You cannot use it that way, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21911407/use-css-calc-in-jquery) may help you.

Comment: Otherwise, jQuery does understand pixels, and `.8vw` is 0.8% of the viewport, which can easily be calculated in JS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `vw` is a unit of measure equal to 1% of the width of the viewport, we can calculate the `calc()` statements into a value jQuery can understand.

```js
var time = true

$('#toggle').click(function () {
  time = !time;
  
  if (time === true) {
    // calc(-15px + .8vw)
    var calc = -15 + (0.08 * $(window).width()) + "px";
    $("#message").animate({ marginTop: calc });
  } else {
    // calc(0px + .8vw)
    var calc = 0 + (0.08 * $(window).width()) + "px";
    $("#message").animate({ marginTop: calc });
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="toggle">Toggle</button>
<div id="message">Message</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the JavaScript alternative to `calc()`.

Basically I calculate my on vw unit values with this line:

```
var vw_value = $(window).width() / 100 * 0.8;
```

Working fiddle here. Just change the `time` variable to 0 to see the difference:

```js
var time = 0;

var vw_value = $(window).width() / 100 * 0.8;

if (time == 1) {
  $("#one").animate({ marginTop: vw_value - 15 + "px" });
} else {
  $("#one").animate({ marginTop: vw_value + "px" });
}
```

```css
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#one{
    margin-top:0;
    width: 40px;
    background:grey;
    height:40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="one"></div>
```